# "Documents" or "document"

Tags: word-choice

I know that *document* is an uncountable noun.

But I see some people write

> A lot of **documents** were found.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that sentence, *documents* is the obvious choice.

> A lot of *document* were found.

The above is incorrect; *were* is for a pluralized noun. As well, *a lot of* can only be used in front of a pluralized noun. For it to be proper English, you must pluralize *documents*.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than being an uncountable noun, *[document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document)* is indeed countable.  It is used as an example of a countable noun in [keio.ac.jp/~hjb/countable.uncountable.html](http://web.hc.keio.ac.jp/~hjb/countable.uncountable.html) and in [1-language.com/englishcourse](http://www.1-language.com/englishcourse/unit9_grammar.htm).  Thus "A lot of documents were found" exhibits correct grammar, although some English teachers frown upon "A lot of" and would recommend "Many documents were found" instead.

Comment: Perhaps the OP was thinking of *[documentation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/documentation#Noun)* rather than *document*.